# Do I need a tune with minor bolt-ons?

Tags: chevrolet, car, camaro, custom, tune-up

2015 Chevy Camaro. I'm currently thinking of getting a cold air intake and also a new exhaust system on my car. Is it detrimental to tune it or can I pass by without doing so? I don't really race anywhere and just do daily driving, but still just want to have fun with what I can try to do.

Comment: You can do as much as you want, the limit is usually the contents of your wallet.

Comment: The other issue besides cost is will it pass your local emission inspection.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: [Related question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25111/675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Since you didn't put the model of your Camaro, I'm talking specifically to the V8 version, whether an LS3 or L99 version. What I'm stating will apply to the V6 version as well, but without as much gain as with the V8 (obviously).

Depending on what you consider a "new exhaust system". If you are looking for a typical "cat back" system, you can get by with out a tune in most cases. If you are looking to install headers, then you should really consider a tune as the two together is where you're going to get your best performance gains without the worry of creating issues.

Something to consider with the 5th gen Camaro exhaust system is they are pretty free flowing in the first place. For a stock system, they do quite well. The only real gains which you'd see is if you put headers on there, unless you are just looking for the exhaust note.

As for the cold air intake, these too can be installed without tuning the vehicle. With both systems upgrades you will see some performance improvement, but don't expect it to be a whole different car. The biggest thing you'll notice is how it sounds. The "butt dyno" (seat of the pants feel from the upgrades) may lie to you, with you thinking you have a lot more improvement than is actually there. I wouldn't expect anything greater than a 15-20 wheel horsepower improvement with both upgrades if you don't have a tune installed as well. The tune is where you'd see the biggest gains, which you could see output increase in the 30-40 whp range overall. Mind you, this is all dependent on the systems installed and the tuner used. No two systems or tuners are going to do the same exact things, so be wary of false claims and expect only modest gains.

Answer (score -1):

You won't need a tune for the air intake, but you'll want one for the exhaust system. You can find a tune you can do yourself.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFw8fUkQqxE&t=3s

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers as they can go stale quickly - instead please add a summary of the link so that your answer remains valid even if the link fails.